# CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer() always returns nil on my AVCaptureStillImageOutput capture callback block

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, video-capture, core-image

I'm writing a microscopy application for MacOS (latest everything, Obj-C).
I use an `AVCaptureSession` to preview live video from microscope camera on-screen, but I also want to let the user take still images when they recognize something interesting. I wish to save the highest possible quality image to a file on disk.

For that I try to use an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`, which by the headers is what I need. I set it up, and add it to my capture-session like thus:

```
self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];    
NSDictionary *compressionSettings = @{AVVideoQualityKey : @(1.0)};
NSDictionary *outputSettings = @{ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG,
                                  AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : compressionSettings,
                                  AVVideoWidthKey : @(1024),
                                  AVVideoHeightKey : @(768)
                                  };
[self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];    
[self.session addOutput: stillImageOutput];
```

Later on, as user selects to take a  snapshot - I call on this method to try to capture a still image:

```
// Capture a single video frame during a video capture
-(BOOL)captureStillImage: (CGRect)cropRect {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }
    if (videoConnection == nil) { return NO };

    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:
     ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

         CVImageBufferRef imageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer); 
         if(imageBufferRef==nil) // <<< HERE I ALWAYS GET NULL
             return;

         NSCIImageRep *imageRep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:imageBufferRef]];

         NSImage *compositeImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[imageRep size]];
         NSImage *videoFrameImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[imageRep size]];
         [videoFrameImage addRepresentation:imageRep];
         NSRect r = NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, [imageRep size].width, [imageRep size].height);
         [compositeImage lockFocus];
         [videoFrameImage drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0f, 0.0f) fromRect:r operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0f];
         [compositeImage unlockFocus];

         NSData *tiffImageData = [videoFrameImage TIFFRepresentation];
         NSBitmapImageRep *tiffRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:tiffImageData];
         NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
         tiffImageData = [tiffRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:imageProps];

         // Save data to file
         static NSUInteger imageNumber = 0;
         NSString *imageFilePath = [@"/Users/me/Desktop/" stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%lu", imageNumber++]];
         imageFilePath = [imageFilePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"JPG"];
         [tiffImageData writeToFile: imageFilePath atomically: NO];
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

I found similar questions of other users - but the answers always involved "you did not apply "OutputSettings" which I do - so I'm really stumped here.

As a side note: if I use the "shorthand" API:

```
     NSData *pixelData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
```

in my callback - it succeeds, but the pixelData contains a poor, low resolution, and small image - certainly not the quality I see in my preview. Furthermore - it is JPEG compressed - so If I want to crop it, I will need to decode, then crop, then re-compress - thus further reducing the already-low quality. That's why I try to use the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` object.

Can anyone shed light, or direct me to the correct docs on this? I've been putting too much time on it already, and the plethora of frameworks involved (CoreMedia, CoreVideo, CoreImage, AVFoundation) are really not well documented, or have any reasonable architecture one can grasp. Gee I miss QuickTime Components and the old APIS.

Help please? anyone?

Comment: Are you sure `imageSampleBuffer` itself is not `NULL` and `error` is empty? Also how did you set up your capture session? As far as I know it must be configured with the `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` preset in order to support still image capture.

Comment: It is never nil, and as I stated - I can successfully use jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation on it, and receive the image. very poor quality and size though.

Answer (score 0):

`CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` returns nil because you requested JPEG-compressed images by using AVVideoCodecJPEG. The sample buffer isn't going to contain a raw uncompressed image buffer, it's going to contain a single block buffer containing the jpeg data.

You don't want to use AVVideoCodecKey, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey, etc in  your dictionary, you want to specify the CVPixelFormatType and other settings so it returns back to you uncompressed frames. See the discussion at the top of the AVVideoSettings.h header.

Comment: I tried many things. The reason I specify JPEG in the code sample above, is that I suspected the FireWire microscope camera was actually providing JPEG compressed images, and that I may need guess what is the actual "thing" in the imageSampleBuffer. Of course I might be wrong.

Comment: I easily drowned in AVVideoSettings.h and cannot make any sense of it. Can you be so kind to offer a link to conceptual documentation that explains the intricate interface between AVFoundation, CoreMedia, CoreVideo, and my humble code in my application? I fail to build this unstructured set of attributes to work. Should they describe "compressed image data" or "pixel buffer"? "whats in the input" or "what I want as output", and how do I tell what I CAN get as output? I want a VERY simple thing. Save the current frame. I fail to find any reasonable API to do that.

Comment: You're not going to find one piece of documentation that answers every question you have. Each piece is individually documented, and it's up to you to connect the dots. The best way to do that is to simply read the documentation for every single related piece of API. If there's something you don't understand, look for sample code. It helps to try to learn all parts of the API rather than learning how to do one specific thing, because then the pieces start fitting together.

Comment: The output is what the API is *giving you*, so the dictionary is how you specify what you want it to give you. This is why you want to specify an uncompressed buffer, not a JPEG. The discussion at the top of the AVVideoSettings.h header explains how to do that. Mainly, specify the pixel format: kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as something such as kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA. Then the API will give you  uncompressed BGRA pixel buffers which you can create the CIImage etc from.